# CRM Dialog create entity and pass data

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, customization

Could anybody give any piece of advice, or code, or documentation link where I can found:

- how to bind 'entity creation' after dialog is closed with positive
  result,
- and change some field on his parent entity, if dialog is closed with
  negative (cancel) status?

I also want to know how to pass data from and to dialog.

I am talking about custom aspx dialog (like dlg_closeopp.aspx) not standard dialog which is 'Process' entity.

I call my dialog with the following js code which is bound on OnFieldChange event of Contact entity:

```
function onFieldChange() {
    var oUrl = Mscrm.CrmUri.create("/SFA/conts/dlg_newone.aspx");
    var callbackFunction = Mscrm.Utilities.createCallbackFunctionObject("performActionAfterDialogClose", this);
    var ret_val = openStdDlgWithCallback(oUrl, document, 450, 420, callbackFunction);
}

function performActionAfterDialogClose(ret_val) {
    if (ret_val) {
        //Do Anything here
    }
}
```

I need to create an activity if the user-chosen data on the dialog meets my conditions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass entity data to the dialog:

```
oUrl.get_query()['DialogId'] = dialogId;
oUrl.get_query()['ObjectId'] = entityId;
oUrl.get_query()['EntityName'] = objectTypeCode;
```

Use the callback to get the result:

```
ret_val.setCallbackReference(function (result) { //created record based on result });
```

Use can use the SDK to create records based on the result.