# Dynamics CRM 2016 Online - Refresh record after using dialog

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom button on my ribbon which fires a dialog up. It's part of a workaround Qualification solution I'm putting together.

The creation of an Account/Contact/Opportunity and the choices given work fine, as well as changing the status of the Lead to qualified. The problem is that when the user is done with the Dialog and closes it, they're still looking at the Lead in its original state.

How do I force the form to refresh so that it shows its new state?

I've seen a Javascript solution online (codeplex), Process.js - callDialog() which seems popular but it doesn't want to work as described by the creator on my version of CRM - always get a invalid URL error message & it fires on load of the form as well as when using the custom button.

Has anyone come across a requirement like this and how have you resolved it?

Thanks

Edit: Here is the JS I use on my ribbon button currently. Where do I put my refresh call and what/how do I call the event being used when closing the Dialog.
I tried adding a refresh call at the bottom of the this code but its called whilst opening the Dialog at the start, which isn't much use as the changes I want to see are applied throughout the Dialog itself.
Thanks

```js
Develop1_RibbonCommands_runDialogForm = function(objectTypeCode, dialogId) {
    var primaryEntityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    var rundialog = Mscrm.CrmUri.create('/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx');
    rundialog.get_query()['DialogId'] = dialogId;
    rundialog.get_query()['ObjectId'] = primaryEntityId;
    rundialog.get_query()['EntityName'] = objectTypeCode;
    var hostWindow = window;
        if (typeof(openStdWin) == 'undefined') {
            hostWindow = window.parent; // Support for Turbo-forms in CRM2015 Update 1
        }
        if (typeof(hostWindow.openStdWin) != 'undefined') {
            hostWindow.openStdDlgWithCallback(rundialog, hostWindow.buildWinName(null), 615, 480, Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false));
        } 
}
})();
```

Comment: Hi alex, You can write javascript for ribbon button. You just need to run dialog using javascript and use below code to refresh the form `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName(), Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Xrm.Page.data (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx), you'll want to call `Xrm.Page.data.refresh()`.

Depending on how you're launching your dialog, and assuming your dialog is a webresource hosted in CRM, the dialog can reach back out to the form it launched from and call refresh, or a callback could potentially be used.

**EDIT (based on your posted code):** If the 5th parameter of the function `openStdDlgWithCallback` is the callback for when the dialog closes you'd want to pass the function like `Xrm.Page.data.refresh` or wrap your call in a function `function(){Xrm.Page.data.refresh()}`. Currently your code is executing the function right away which is why you're seeing the refresh right away.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've added my JS to the original post - please can you help with your suggestion.

Comment: Will try this out first thing in the morning and report back. Thanks!

Comment: it worked! thanks so much for your help with this. My next challenge will be to lock the form whilst waiting for the refresh to happen. After closing the dialog, it takes a few seconds, with a editable form in front of the user, for the refresh to kick.

Answer (score 0):

Using [openStdDlgWithCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286452/crm-dialog-create-entity-and-pass-data/39308346#39308346) you can subscribe a callback function which runs after the dialog is closed. You can then use `Xrm.Page.data.refresh()` inside the callback function.

Comment: This does seem to do a refresh but it fires before the Dialog has opened. If I change a field and then hit the custom button, it asks if I want to save changes first - If I click OK to carryon regardless, it refreshes the form (reverting my changes) and then opens the Dialog. I need this to happen in the reverse order ha!

Comment: OK done, whilst also working out how to correctly add code to posts on here!